# Как с помощью вложенного цикла вывести 0 либо 1 либо х?

Tags: javascript

Помогите с задачей, пожалуйста.

С помощью вложенных циклов, нужно вывести рисунок:

> 10x01x
>
> 10x01x
>
> 10x01x

Внешний цикл выводит перенос строки br. Вложенный цикл от 0 до 6 выводит либо 0 либо 1 либо х.

Не могу додуматься, как сделать?

```js
function t6() {
  let out6 = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    for (let k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
      out6 += k;
    }
    out6 += '<br>';
  }

  document.querySelector('.out-6').innerHTML = out6;
}

document.querySelector('.b-6').onclick = t6;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="b-6">Task-6</button>
<div class="out-6"></div>
```

Comment: Непонятный какой-то "рисунок". А вместо внутреннего цикла сделать `out6 += "10x01x<br/>";` считается нечестным? Обязательно вложенный цикл - бессмысленный и беспощадный?

Comment: Это слишком просто будет))) Нужно как-то высчитать.

Comment: По какой-то формуле высчитать или достаточно будет завести массив на 6 фиксированных элементов и вместо `out6 += k` делать `out6 += values[k]`?

Comment: Это задача, которую нужно каким-то образом решить, только как? Во внутреннем цикле, мы создали счетчик k. Теперь как-то нужно, когда k == 0 или k == 4 мы выводим 1, и дальше прописываем другие условия.

Comment: Либо тремя `if`-ами, либо маппингом (в данном случае можно через массив)

Comment: Не могли бы вы пример if-ми написать? Если вас не затруднит.

Comment: Почему вас затрудняет написать два других if'а, которые по сути ничем не отличаются от того, что у вас написано в комментарии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let o6 = document.querySelector('.out-6')
for (let i = 1; i < 4 ; i++) {
    for (let k = 1; k < 25; k++) {
        if((k % 2 == 0) && !(k % 3 == 0)){
            o6.innerHTML += '0';
        }else if ((k % 2 == 1) && !(k % 3 == 0)) {
            o6.innerHTML += '1';
        }else{
            o6.innerHTML += 'x';
        }
    }
    o6.innerHTML += '<br>';
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Судя по образцу каждый третий проход цикла должен быть 'x', значит нужна проверка на кратность трем, но цикл по условию начинает работу с 0 а не с 1 и делать (k%3==0) не получится так как по счетчику цикла k будет равно 2 когда необходимо давать 'x'   поэтому надо в проверке добавлять +1, выглядит это так (k + 1) % 3 == 0

```js
function t6() {
  let out = document.querySelector('.out-6');
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    str += '<br>';
    for (let k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
      if ((k + 1) % 3 == 0) {// 
        str += 'x';
      } else if (k % 2 == 0) {
        str += 1;
      } else {
        str += 0;
      }
    }
  }
  out.innerHTML = str;
}

document.querySelector('.b-6').onclick = t6;
```

```html
<button class="button-primary b-6">Task</button>
<div class="out-6"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function t6() {
    let out6 = document.querySelector('.out-6');
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
            if (k == 2 || k == 5) {
                out6.innerHTML += 'x';
            }
            else if (k % 2 == 0) {
                out6.innerHTML += 1;
            }
            else {
                out6.innerHTML += 0;
            }
        }
        out6.innerHTML += '<br>';
    }
}
t6();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]